# Made massive oversight in specifying question. How to proceed?

Tags: discussion

In this algorithms [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/102987/update-each-element-to-product-of-all-others-in-linear-time-constant-additional), I asked how to solve an algorithms question from a book, which I later realised I completely misread. The question I asked still led to some interesting discussion, but I don't think that it is possible to solve. As per the question in the book, you are in fact meant to return a *new* array, and not modify the original one.

One of the commenters called Vince, gave an answer which with slight modification, would have been correct had I specified the question correctly. I incorporated this answer into my question as an example of an insufficient solution alongside my own one, which had difference complexity characteristics. The comments which I took Vince's answer from seem to have disappeared.

In light of my error, I am now wondering how to proceed. Should I rename the question and correct it, posting Vince's now correct solution, or should the question just be deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no soon to be invalidated answer, so you can do as you wish, but with interesting problem it would be a waste to delete it.

There are ways that seem plausible:

- modify question and notify Vince
- modify question and answer yourself
- if modification greatly affects question, you could ask separate one

Comment: I would like to modify it to the correct question and post Vince's answer. Vince has removed his comments, so should I mention that the answer was written by an anonymous user?

Comment: @jpcooper He is not anonymous, mayhap mention by name or just drop it, answer on its own is for future users.